# Не могу прочитать описание картинки pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Скрипт автоответов для чат бота. Когда бот начнет запрашивать капчу, хочу отправлять сообщение себе на второй аккаунт. Капчу идентифицирую по тексу под картинкой с самой капчей.

````
async def spam(client: Client, message):
    
    if "Нашёл кое-кого для тебя!" in message.text:#текст, на который будет реагировать срипт
        time.sleep(1)#указать задержку ответа бота или закомментить, если задержка не нужна
        await app.send_message(chat_id,"")
        time.sleep(1)
        await app.send_message(chat_id,"")#вписать свой текст или закомментить строку, если текст не нужен

 
    elif "Диалог остановлен" in message.text:#текст, на который будет реагировать срипт, если вдруг несколько вариантов
        time.sleep(1)#указать задержку ответа бота или закомментить, если задержка не нужна
        await app.send_message(chat_id,"/next")
        
    elif "У вас нет собеседника" in message.text:#текст, на который будет реагировать срипт, если вдруг несколько вариантов
        time.sleep(1)#указать задержку ответа бота или закомментить, если задержка не нужна
        await app.send_message(chat_id,"/start")
        
    
    elif "Чтобы подтвердить, что" in message.caption:#текст, на который будет реагировать срипт, если вдруг несколько вариантов
        time.sleep(1)#указать задержку ответа бота или закомментить, если задержка не нужна
        await app.send_message(my_id,"КАПЧА")```
````